# Show post by slug sanitize_title

Tags: slug

They help me as is the right way to do this.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'spa',
    'name' => 'echo sanitize_title(news_get_meta('gamers'));'
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Except the title of the post is

**`echo sanitize_title(news_get_meta('gamers'));`**

I'm assuming `news_get_meta` is a function particular to a theme or plugin you have installed, so your query should be:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'spa',
    'name'      => sanitize_title( news_get_meta('gamers') );
) );
```

Comment: You're welcome, you should tick it as the correct answer and also upvote